# Bucle for aplicado a una matriz en JavaScript

Tags: javascript

El código de abajo lista en pantalla los cuatro valores de la matriz `const nums`.

Sin embargo, al usar `text +=` lo que esperaría es que la variable `text` repitiese su valor antes de añadir el nuevo valor con cada nuevo ciclo dando lugar al siguiente resultado en pantalla:

1. Uno
2. Uno Dos
3. Uno DosTres
4. Uno Dos Tres Cuatro

Mi suposición errónea es que al transportar la lógica del operador `+=` a la tabla `ol` de HTML se añada un nuevo valor de la matriz a los ya existentes por cada ciclo.

Dado esto, me surgen dos dudas.

1. Si todos los valores del array son de tipo `string`, ¿por qué no
   añade el valor que ya tiene al usar el operando?
2. ¿Qué debería hacer para que cada nuevo elemento `li` de la tabla contenga los valores anteriores antes de añadir el nuevo valor?

```js
const nums = ["Uno", "Dos", "Tres", "Cuatro"];
let fLen = nums.length;

let text = "<ol>";
for (let i = 0; i < fLen; i++) {
  text += "<li>" + nums[i] + "</li>";
}
text += "</ol>";

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>Arrays</h2>

<p>Los primeros cuatro numerales son:</p>

<p id="demo"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Porque el operador += añade la información a la actual, pero reinicia su valor al guardarlo. "a"+="b"="ab" y no "aab"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Si todos los valores del array son de tipo `string`, ¿por qué no añade el valor que ya tiene al usar el operando?**

Estás presuponiendo que se agregará el contenido acumulado de los elementos anteriores del listado al contenido del nuevo, pero lo que estás haciendo es, realmente, agregar más HTML a una variable que contiene solo código HTML.

Cada iteración `nums[i]` contiene el elemento en curso, independientemente de lo que contenga la variable `text`, y no el texto acumulado, de modo que eso es lo que agregarás a cada elemento del listado HTML `<li>` que estás creando.

---

**¿Qué debería hacer para que cada nuevo elemento `li` de la tabla contenga los valores anteriores antes de añadir el nuevo valor?**

Para conseguir lo que deseas debes almacenar la suma de las cadenas de manera independiente al HTML que generas y, además, agregar dicho valor a cada elemento de la lista en vez de el elemento en curso:

```js
const nums = ["Uno", "Dos", "Tres", "Cuatro"];
let fLen = nums.length;

/* Aquí acumulamos los elementos uno tras otro */
let cadena = ""
let text = "<ol>";
for (let i = 0; i < fLen; i++) {
  /* Ahora debemos agregar a la cadena el valor curso */
  cadena += nums[i];
  /* Y mostrar en el HTML lo que llevamos acumulado */
  text += "<li>" + cadena + "</li>";
}
text += "</ol>";

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>Arrays</h2>

<p>Los primeros cuatro numerales son:</p>

<p id="demo"></p>

</body>
</html>
```